# Javascript hyperlink(.link) open in new tab

Tags: javascript

I had used a javascript .link to generate a hyperlink as below

```
$element.html(indicator.link(domain));
```

But the URL opens at the same page as originally the link clicked. How can I make it to be opened in new tab?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this:

```js
function myFunction() {
  var str = "Free Web Building Tutorials!";
  var result = str.link("https://www.google.co.in");
  document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = result;

}
```

```html
<button onclick="myFunction()">Try it</button>
<p id="demo"></p>
```

Comment: It should be a hyperlink and not button click. Also the link are directly place to web through .html

Answer (score 0):

> function setMyAdd()
>       {
>           window.open(myLink);
>       }